# Porque triggerHandler só está afetando o primeiro da lista?

Tags: jquery

Estou tentando chamar os handler de um evento via jquery, entretando o método `triggerHandler` só está afetando um dos elementos selecionados, sendo que o seletor definitivamente representa vários elementos.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kAb5u/)

O triggerHandler é chamado dentro do evento de um check-box para alterar os valores de vários outros check-boxes, com o mesmo valor dele. Definir a propriedade 'checked' para todos os outros check-boxes funciona, entretanto o triggerHandler não.

O que eu estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade creio que você não esteja errado exatamente. O que ocorre é que `jQuery.fn.triggerHandler` realmente só dispara o evento para o primeiro nó.

No seu caso não se aplicaria o uso de `jQuery.fn.trigger`?

Talvez algo como isto:

```
$('.foo').trigger('change');
```

Comment: Se aplica sim... algo na minha mente disse que `trigger("change")` iria fazer com que o checkbox alternasse de estado, como se eu estivesse simulando a alteração.